# How to have a free width column based on the row width in the table?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

and I have the following code:

```js
return (
  <Box sx={{ height: 400 }}>
    <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} />
  </Box>
)
```

and I am having the table getting rendered as:
[image]

**I want the column of the `email` to take the width of the widest row cell automatically**, so I want the table to render as follows:

[image]

My colums and rows look simply as follows:

```js
const columns = [ { field: "firstName" }, { field: "lastName" }, ...etc ]
const rows = [ 
   { firstName: "Camil Pasa Sokak", lastName: "In The Village", ...etc },
   ... etc
]
```

How to do it in MUI x (community table, the free one)?

> I want the column of the `email` to take the width of the widest row cell automatically

- **please note**: since the table is wide, it will automatically show you a scrollbar (x and y scrollbars). I want to keep this functionality, I want to keep these scrollbars (from the x and y) I don't want to disable them.

Here's a sandbox instnce:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-newton-z6pwj4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: did you try colspan?

Comment: @UmairFarooq, no?

Comment: It would help if you could create a fiddle or pen showing the issue. A basic html table should do what you need by default, so we really need to play around with a live example with a MUI table.

Comment: @RyanWheale, OK, creating...

Comment: Done @RyanWheale,  https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-newton-z6pwj4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs for the datatable component you are using, it's not super clear the best way to go about it. The crux of the problem is that this is a div + flexbox table and not a true html table. As such, cells within a single column are not really "bound" to each other the same way as a regular html table.

There is a page which addresses [column dimensions](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-dimensions/), but I could not find a satisfactory solution there. I was particularly disappointed that `maxWidth` seems to do nothing. The closest I got was setting a fixed column width, but I don't think that's what you want:

```js
const columns = [{
  field: "email", width: 300,
}]
```

So then I moved on to their [styling cells](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/#styling-cells) page, which allows you to have much more control over styling, but this still doesn't work because one flex cell does not affect the size of all flex cells in a column - each row has a different sized cell based on the size of the email address.

```
const columns = [{
  field: "email", cellClassName: "foobar",
}]

<DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} sx={{
  "& .foobar": {
    maxWidth: "300px !important"
  }
}} />
```

So, my best suggestion is to loop over the data, find the longest email address, and set the fixed `width` based on that. This kinda sucks, but I don't see another way to properly set dimensions for a flexbox-based table:

```js
const longestEmail = rows.reduce((longest, row) => {
    return row.email.length > longest.length ? row.email : longest
}, '');

const columns = [{
  // play around with the multiplier until you find a suitable width
  field: "email", width: longestEmail.length * 9,
}]
```

Comment: I was thinking yesterday, what if we can make the columns re-sizable? is it possible in MUI X data grids (the community free version) if we wrote extra code?

Comment: Anything is possible. I doubt they wrote the code to prevent you from doing it. When you do it, you will want to set the `width` value on the correct column within the `columns` array. If you plan to open source it, make sure you check their TOC to make sure you're allowed to implement and distribute "premium" features for free.

Answer (score -1):

This is from the Documentation..[Number Signature](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-spanning/#number-signature)

```js
<DataGrid
  columns={[
    { field: 'username', colSpan: 2, hideable: false },
    {
      field: 'organization',
      sortable: false,
      filterable: false,
      hideable: false,
    },
    { field: 'age', hideable: false },
  ]}
  rows={rows}
  {...other}
/>
```

you can use colspan but it sets all cells in the column to span a given number of columns.

```js
const columns = [{
  field: "email",colSpan:2,
},]
```

Comment: Oh no... Sorry to say that. it's not colSpan, colSpan will merge two cells together, I didn't mean that, I meant that I want the cell `email` to have free width, based on the rows (it's a column header, so I mean all the rows underneath it).

Comment: "to have a free width" = to get the width of the widest row underneath it. This is the default behavior in the normal `<Table>` component. I wanted to bring that same behavior to the MUI X DataGrid table

Comment: This is explained in the picture above